# Is it possible to create multiple instances of the Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows-server-2008, high-availability, task-scheduler

I have a 2-node Windows Failover Cluster that I have clustered the Task Scheduler in to run my batch application. However I have certain tasks (backups, log rotation, etc) that need to run daily on each node independent of the cluster. Is there a way to setup a second instance of the Task Scheduler that runs independent of the clustered one?

Comment: some how this hurts my head

Comment: Use a third-party task scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 2008 server, you have the new task scheduler. You should be able to set up an event-triggered task to enable/disable the other scheduled tasks.  You just have to identify the failover event in the event logs, and use that as the task trigger.  You should also be able to leverage the taskscheduler module in the [powershell pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack)

Comment: I think this is a good starting point for me to try out.

Answer (score 0):

Run the tasks on a machine that is not a member of the cluster.

Comment: I only have the 2-nodes and they are both part of the cluster.

Comment: Ah. 3rd party tool then or maybe Jim B's cool suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid a third-party task scheduler, you can try to configure your tasks (backups, log rotation, etc) as manual services on each node, then use the cluster's task scheduler to start those services on demand.

[How to create a service with sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)

You may need to use srvany or winserv to make a script runnable as a service.